# creating a filesystem in a file in windows

Tags: windows, mount

In linux we can create a filesystem in single file and mount it. Is there any way to create a filesystem in a file in windows and mount the filesystem created in a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows 7 you can use diskpart to do this.

Save the command lines to a text file, such as c:\newdisk.txt. This example will create a 500 MB virtual disk and mount it:

```
 create vdisk file=c:\test.vhd maximum=500 type=fixed
 sel vdisk file=c:\test.vhd
 attach vdisk
```

Execute the script with diskpart:

```
 diskpart /s c:\newdisk.txt
```

You can also format the volume, assign a drive letter, etc with diskpart.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7/2008 it is simple to mount a VHD file:

http://thelazyadmin.com/blogs/thelazyadmin/archive/2009/01/15/mount-a-vhd-within-windows-7-server-2008-r2.aspx

VHD is a "virtual hard disk" normally used to host a virtual OS, but you could certainly create an empty one as a single file based file system...

Comment: That link is dead, [archived version¨](http://web.archive.org/web/20110612162136/http://thelazyadmin.com/blogs/thelazyadmin/archive/2009/01/15/mount-a-vhd-within-windows-7-server-2008-r2.aspx)